# Natural Representation of Factor Group $G/H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $G$ be the positive reals under multiplication and let $H$ be numbers $2^i$ where $i \in \mathbb{Z}$.

a) Show H is a subgroup of G
b) Show H is a normal subgroup of G

Those two are no problem, the next part is what I am stuck on.

c) Give a natural representation of the factor group G/H. Each element should be uniquely describable as $\overline{a}$ where a ranges over some natural set. (Ex $3.1$ and $12.4$ as $\overline{3.1}=\overline{12.4}$) Have the identity represented as $\overline{1}$.

d) Find all elements $\overline{a}$ in G/H whose cube (in G/H) is the identity. (There are three solutions)

Attempt:

Parts a and b were fine, however for part c we know that $2^i$  is in H so $\overline{2^i}$  = $\overline{1}$. We want to show that g($2^i$)  for some $g \in G$. (positive reals under multiplication) this gives a natural representation. I'm not entirely sure if this is what it means or if this is the right approach. Any hint in the right direction would help, as well as for part d as I think I need part c for part d.

Comment: Your question would be a lot easier to read if you used a bit of $\LaTeX$ markup.  I will edit it, but you should look at the edits to make sure that it reflects your original intent.

Comment: I added the latex edits to include what I meant.

Comment: Some hints: Can you think of an interval of positive reals, such that dividing any number in the interval by $2$ or multiplying any number in the interval by $2$ will give a number outside the interval? For the last one: think about the roots of the polynomial $x^3 - 2^i$ and what happens for various $i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer part **c)**, note that $\overline{x} = \overline{x \cdot 2^i}$ for any $i \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Thus, each $x$ in an interval $[2^k, 2^{k + 1})$ provides a distinct coset representative and all cosets are represented.  Which $k$ to use?

For part **d)**, you need to solve the equation $\overline{x^3} = \overline{1}$ in $G/H$.  In the group $G$, you have:  $x^3 = 1 \cdot 2^i$ for some $i \in \mathbb{Z}$.  This doesn't give an integer's worth of solutions though.  Here's a hint why:  for any integer $n$, $2^{i + 3n} = \left( 2^n \right) ^3 \cdot 2^i$.

Comment: You would want to use k=0 so a is in [1,2) because anything between that interval will give the rest of the set. And part d should be 2^(1/3), and 4^(1/3) because those will give the identity element when cubed.